# Converting String (in Eastern Daylight Time format) to Date in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, postgresql, date-format

Please I need help on how to convert this string [ **Fri Jun 19 10:45:39 EDT 2009**
] that is in EDT date format back to Date in SQL (Am using Postgres). I want to be able to have something like this 19-06-2009

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CAST('Fri Jun 19 10:45:39 EDT 2009' AS date),   -- to get datatype DATE
    TO_CHAR(CAST('Fri Jun 19 10:45:39 EDT 2009' AS date), 'DD-MM-YYYY') -- formated date, a string
```